# Wanted to use Google Map API in desktop client

Tags: google-maps

I want to use th Google Map API for my desktop tool.As I dont want to show any Map control in the UI I just want to give some address to API and the google should return me the city,country,zip etc.

Please tell me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the Google Maps API in a situation where you're not going to display a map. From [the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/):

> Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the [Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12).

I suspect you'll need to look for other commercial solutions for your situation.

Note that although I work for Google, this post is not made on behalf of Google - it's just based on the public documentation.

Comment: Thanks Jon,We are able to create a utility using Google Map where we give the raw address as a Text and Google API return us the  Address in standardized way i.e. city,country,zip extracted without using any MAP control in UI,but this utility is in JSP and Servlets.I want to create a desktop based application for this.Will this be possible?

Comment: @AmandeepSingh: It's technically very simple to make a request to the geocoding API - but you need to read the terms and conditions around where you can use the results.

Comment: Thanks Jon for replying as I read this http://geo-google.sourceforge.net/usage.html and found that we can make 15000 requests from one IP address per day using one key.Is this much available for free user?And can we use this in a desktop application(Is it technically possible?).

Comment: @AmandeepSingh: I doubt that the request limit per day is a problem - but the type of your application and your usage of the API may well be.

Comment: John Thanks for taking my attention to this issue,issue of usage of API can be a problem and context of usage also is a important factor.My question is,is it technically possible to use this API(For non commercial use) to build a desktop application to standardize the bulk records.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh: You'd have to look at the terms and conditions very closely, and possibly contact the Maps API team directly - I'm afraid I can't speak for them, and I'm certainly not a lawyer :( The *technical* side shouldn't be a problem, unless you've got more than 15,000 records to check per day.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon for your support,It is really appreciable as you took my attention in the right perspective and direction.I may shortly contact for the same with the team once I will be sure about the technical feasibility of the project.